# SQL query with 2 where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am firing a query like

```
declare @aID varchar(max)='1,2'
declare @TypeId int=23
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'SELECT * from Table1
  WHERE 
   AID IN ('+@aID+')
    AND TypeId = @TypeId

  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  begin
  exec(@sql)
  end
```

Here, I get the result where 'aID' is IN (1,2) and TypeId =23.
**`But I want that result for all rows where aID IN (1,2), even though TypeId !=23. Plus I want results where TypeId =23 and I dont care what 'aID' it is.`**

Can anyone tell me what should I change ?

Comment: It sounds like you want to do an `OR` instead of `AND`?  BTW, you clearly didn't transcribe your SQL code correctly.  It has syntax errors.

Comment: Use `or` statement like `where aID in (1,2) or typeID != 23`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is not right. You can change it

```
set @sql = 'SELECT * from Table1
  WHERE 
   AID IN ('+@aID+') OR TypeId ='+ @TypeId
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OR instead of AND.

```
SELECT * from Table1
WHERE (AID IN ('+@aID+'))
    OR (TypeId = @TypeId)
```

With AND, both conditions must be true. With OR, only one (or both) condition needs to be true.

Here's an example.

```
SELECT UserFirstName, UserLastName
FROM Users
WHERE UserFirstName = 'Bob' AND UserLastName = 'Johnson'
```

returns

```
Bob | Johnson
```

but,

```
SELECT UserFirstName, UserLastName
FROM Users
WHERE UserFirstName = 'Bob' OR UserLastName = 'Johnson'
```

returns

```
Bob | Johnson
Bob | Marley
Tom | Johnson
```